# Convert an Eigen3 Transform's rotation into an AngleAxis

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, eigen, eigen3

How can this be done using Eigen 3?

```
#include <Eigen/Geometry>

Affine3d transform;
AngleAxisd aa = ...;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, I found the answer shortly after posting the question.

```
Affine3d transform;
AngleAxisd aa(transform.rotation());
```

Naturally this discards any translation component in the original affine transformation.